# RSA/ECB/nopadding В GO

Tags: golang, rsa

Необходимо расшифровать 128байтный слайс информации зашифрованный с помощью публичного ключа.
Приватный ключ имеется , имеется также механизм расшифровки в Java :

```
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/nopadding");
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, client.getRSAPrivateKey());
```

В Golang пробовал:

```
rsa.DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rand.Reader,client.PrivateKey,plainText,[]byte(""))
```

`privateKey.Decrypt()`

И другие способы но не получается расшифровать. Подскажите что нужно делать ?

Comment: Что значит в вашем случае «не получается»?  Ошибка или неверный выход?

Comment: Ошибка crypto/rsa: decryption error

Answer (score 0):

Если заглянуть в исходники функции `rsa.DecryptOAEP` и далее `k := priv.Size()` то не трудно догадаться,что длинна битов открытого ключа меньше шифротекста, но почему то я думаю, что дело в закрытом ключе,а точнее в его импорте в Вашу программу.

Как пример:

```
priv, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pathToKey)
    if err != nil {
        // handling err
    }

    privPem, _ := pem.Decode(priv)
```